# How to pause loop while multithreading is alive

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have 3 threads that are called inside a loop.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DG.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf processData)
    Dim thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf processData2)
    Dim thread3 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf processData3)
    If Not thread1.IsAlive Then
       x1 = i
       thread1.Start()
    ElseIf Not thread2.IsAlive Then
       x2 = i
       thread2.Start()
    ElseIf Not thread3.IsAlive Then
        x3 = i
        thread3.Start()
    End If
Next
```

How do I pause the loop while all threads are alive?
What I want is, if one of the threads finishes then continue the loop and get the (i), then pause the loop again if there are no available threads. Because sometimes DG.Rows items are more than 3.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use three threads to process the rows such that rows 0, 3, 6, etc, are processed  by `processData`, and rows 1, 4, 7, etc, are processed by `processData2` and rows 2, 5, 8, etc by `processData3`, but only three rows at a time?

Comment: I want to process 3 data at the same time,and pause loop while thread1,thread2,thread3 is busy,then continue loop if theres a thread available

Comment: That's still not clear. How are you allocating each row to each processing method?

Answer (score 3):

Let the framework handle this for you: use the [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx).

First, create an array to hold thread status for each item:

```
Dim doneEvents(DG.Rows.Count) As ManualResetEvent
```

Like the `x1`,`x2`,`x3` variables, this needs to be accessible from both your main thread and the `processData` method.

Then modify your `processData` method to accept an `Object` argument at the beginning and set a ResetEvent at the end:

```
Public Sub processData(ByVal data As Object)
   Dim x As Integer = CInt(data)

    '...
    'Existing code here

    doneEvents(x).Set()
End Sub
```

Now you can just queue them all up like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DG.Rows.Count - 1
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(processData, i)
Next
WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents)
Console.WriteLine("All data is processed.")
```

Though I suspect you should also pass the data from your grid for each row to the `processData` method.

You can also use the newer `Async`/`Await` keywords, but I'll have a hard time writing a sample for this without knowing something of the contents of `processData`.

Comment: Thank you so how will i use thread2 and thread3? The reason why i use multithread is to devide my work,because if i only use thread1,processdata tooks 30 seconds,so im trying to work 3 process data at the same time

Comment: The processdata post curl to my server and and sent it back to my tool, it tooks 30 seconds for every grid row response, so i want to devide my work,if tool can process 3 item at the same,it save time and can do fast

Comment: @JuliusMalundras If you want to limit the threadpool to using three threads then you can use the [`SetMaxThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @JuliusMalundras The ThreadPool will use more than one thread. You will have more than one instance of the `processData` function going at the same time. ThreadPool will determine how many instances to used based on your system (how many cores there are) and how busy the operating system is, so you end up with something close to the optimal number of threads running at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this. Don't pause, just launch a thread per loop iteration.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DG.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf processData)
    thread1.Start(i)
Next
```

But in any case, I don't think you want to call `new System.Threading.Thread` in each loop. Those should be moved outside the `For` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help,but what i want is to save time thats why i use 3 threads

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you use TPL's `Parallel` methods and write your code like this:

```
Parallel.For( _
    0, _
    DG.Rows.Count, _
    New ParallelOptions() With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3}, _
    Sub(i) processData(i))
```

I don't understand why you have `processData`, `processData2`, and `processData3` though.